# Adding custom Dll to dotnet libraries

Tags: c#, dll

Hi I want to know is it possible to write a custom DLL in c# and add it to the dotnet framework so I don't have to create a reference to the custom DLL in visual studio just write using "custom DLL namespace" and so on
(Something like c++ shared libraries in Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (decrypting your question, I translate it as "how to install my custom assembly into the GAC), but :

- depending on your scenario (e.g dotnetcore, net5 and multiple targetting deploy environments)
- this is a really, really limited exotic use case, so I guess you rather do not do that.

To answer your exact question :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac